# display image in a splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am a novice android developer. I am trying to create a splash screen. I have a png image.
I have created an empty splash screen with a text box.I have 2 activities - MainActivity and SecondActivity.

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT=2000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SecondActivity.class);
                //Intent is used to switch from one activity to another.

                startActivity(i);
                //invoke the SecondActivity.

                finish();
                //the current activity will get finished.
            }
        }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT);
    }


}


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/geeks"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But app:srcCompat="@drawable/geeks" is in red color. Means it is not resolved. Where shall I copy the png image for the splash screen? I have not copied the image anywhere in android studio. Without the image view, the splash screen runs fine showing hello world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to put your image in `res/drawable` folder:

[image]

and then access it by `app:srcCompat` or `android:src` attribute of `ImageView` inside your `activity_main.xml`:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/company_logo"

android:src="@drawable/company_logo"
```

Comment: the logo is not full_screen in splash screen, the logo shows in center surrounded by white space. How to make it full screen?

Comment: @peepal you need to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 2):

Few things to keep in mind.

1. The image size should be low (not more than 150-200kb)
2. Instead of adding text and image on the activity, design a splash screen using Illustrator or any other medium and save it in png format.
3. Store this in the `res/drawable`.
4. In the activity_main, just add line `android:background ="@drawable/geeks"`.
5. In AndroidManifest.xml, add, `android:theme="@style/Theme.<app name>.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing android : src ="@drawable/geeks", instead.

Comment: where shall i copy the png image for splash screen in drawable folder?

Comment: Inside Drawable itself or if you know to which resolution it belongs then in mipmap.

Comment: image height is 181 pixels, width is 279 pixels; where to place in mipmap. There are 2 folders under mipmap-ic_launcher,ic_launcher_round. How to copy in mipmap? Should I copy the image and paste into mipmap?

Comment: Paste it in mipmap xxxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

put them in `assets` folder. It'll resolve your problem.

Comment: there is no assets folder

Comment: You should create it by yourself